# I need a VPS that lets me upload my own OVF

Tags: vps, ovf

I have an existing VM that I can export as OVF, and I want to just import it wholesale into another VPS. This is a one-time job to help some folks who aren't very tech savvy migrate a service, and I'm trying to minimize my involvement.

Does anybody know a VPS that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked [Linode](http://linode.com) via a tweet if they could do this. They responded with their article, [**Migrate a Server to Your Linode**](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/running-a-custom-linux-distro-on-a-linode-vps). It outlines a procedure for booting Finnix, copying your data, then configuring the VM and rebooting. This isn't what I was looking for, but it will get me there. The bonus is that I already know and love Linode!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet if you haven't already setup the VPS might be to use the Amazon cloud. You can import and export using command line tools via the amazon API or migrate from VMware to amazon EC2 using the provided [Vmware to EC2 connector](http://www.cloudcollege.co.uk/index.php/2011/03/easy-import-of-instances-from-vcentre/).

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: I've just double checked it, all OK at the mo, are you still getting a problem?